# Is there an equivalent to Colander/DictShield for Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, serialization

[Colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/dev/) is a Python Pylons tool used to:

> validate and deserialize data obtained via XML, JSON, an HTML form post or any other equally simple data serialization

It's kind of like an ORM for semi-structured data; to my mind it would be particularly useful if you're dealing with either:

1. Lots of third-party APIs returning XML/JSON in proprietary structures
2. An internal system which needs to serialize and de-serialize the same data (e.g. if you have an internal API to bridge)

I'm working on a Scala project which has both of those requirements - and so I was wondering if there's any equivalent to Colander being worked on for JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) may be a good choice for such a library

Comment: Thanks, marking this as the answer given XStream has limited support for JSON as well as XML (where Simple only does XML)

Answer (score 3):

[Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) is very similar to XStream, but simpler to use.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm definitely going to try this out for XML

Answer (score 2):

For completeness: I ended up going with JAX-RS/JAXB/Jackson. All of the work I wanted to do with de/serialization was related to RESTful APIs, so it made sense to go with a stack that handled more than just the marshalling. I'm finding it very good to work with - especially as it interoperates with Akka Mist out of the box.

Here are some Stack Overflow posts which were helpful background for me:

- [JAX-RS Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80799/jax-rs-frameworks)
- [Scala framework for a Rest API Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678795/scala-framework-for-a-rest-api-server)
- [Java- Jersey, JAX RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019942/java-jersey-jax-rs)

Another alternative is [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/), from the creator of Scala's Spray framework.

For any Pythonistas who come across this question, it's worth noting an alternative to Colander is [DictShield](https://github.com/j2labs/dictshield), from the creator of the async framework Brubeck.

I guess I've learnt that good text serialization/deserialization is typically just a component of larger stacks/frameworks.